# Alternative to using stubs to get rid of cross references

Tags: vb.net, stub

Over 15 years I have created my own "framework" which consists of some classes and some modules.

For example:

```
Strings (contains wrappers for string functions)
Conversions (contains wrappers for conversions)
IO (contains wrappers for IO operations)
Environment (contains Windows environment things9
Windows (deals with currently open windows on Windows)
OEM (contains OEM information for all of my apps)
License (contains things to license my software)
AlphaWindow (contains stuff to display an topmost alpha window)
```

I have created them in such a way that they work as indepenendly from each other as possible so that I can plug them in if I need them.

There are almost no cross references.

However, among around 500 functions, there are still 10 cross references that I just can't rid of.

Because of this, when I create a new project, I'm still forced to add my entire framework.

A really ugly way to resolve this is to use stubs.

For example, my "Strings" class references "Conversions" 10 times.
Now if one project doesn't actually need "Conversions" but does need "Strings", I sometimes make a "Conversions" stub class and add stubs for these 10 functions that "Strings" requires so that my application still compiles.

Is there better looking alternative to these stubs?

I'm not really experienced at C++, but I guess that C++ people are confronted with this problem quite often.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case. What I do is include all the classes in a single DLL. If I need any of the methods, I include a reference to the DLL, there is no harm in the unneeded methods being present.

I use a different namespace for each class (e.g. MyFramework.Strings, MyFramework.Conversions). That way, I can add `Imports` statements only for the framework classes I need to use in a given class.